# Click-Event from MainWindow.xaml.cs in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

so i want to outsource some things from MainWindow.xaml to App.xaml like this for example :

```
<Application x:Class="SVGTesting.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="Test1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="Button1" Click="Button_Click" x:Name="Button1"/>
                    <Button Content="Button2" Click="Button_Click" x:Name="Button2"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In MainWindow.xaml then i have something like this

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Test1}"/>
```

But now VS says that i cannot use the function "Button_Click" because its not in the codebehind from App.xaml. So how can i call this function from MainWindow in App.xaml?

Is there any way? I don't want answers like MVVM or Command. If it's not possible to solve then WPF is unfortunately useless for me.

Thanks and Greetings.

Comment: if you do not want to use the MVVM model its questionable in generall weather WPF makes sense to use. 
But to answer you question:
You could do so by setting the datacontext to the MainWindow and use a command...but you dont want that...so i guess there is no way to achive what you are trying...sorry. Why would you want to do this in the first place maybe we can offer you a solution to your general idea

Comment: because my xaml already has over 400 lines of code. if i would put the whole resources with styles and datatemplates in it too it would be much more lines... i'd like to have just the gui in MainWindow and the resources in other file. maybe it's not possible, then i have to mix 2 resources. one with events and one without events.

Comment: the amount of code required to achive a goal is generally drastically reduced by yousing the MVVM concept. What you could do to tidy up your code by splitting it up is to use pages. Each page has its own code behind and they can be loaded into your mainwindow

Comment: You can't do it, so, _WPF is unfortunately useless_ for you. ;)

Comment: @deintag what are you trying to do? The `Application` object has *nothing* to do with the UI. That's why you never see code in there, in any tutorial. Resources aren't a UI element. Most of the time they're used by multiple windows and models, that's why they're typically stored at the Application level. You can use resources from any window using the appropriate resource path

Comment: @deintag resources are images, strings, fonts. They don't have events. What are you really trying to do? What you ask would be impossible in Winforms and ASP.NET too - you can't add event handlers to the `Application` object of a Winforms application either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the easiest thing to do as WPF expect things to be done in its own way. But there's few options, from easiest to hardest.

**1. Don't do anything**

Easiest way is to keep your data templates inside the MainWindow.xaml.

**2. Use Commands instead of event handlers**

You currently have event handlers defined like this:

```
<Button Content="Button1" Click="Button_Click"
```

"More-WPF way" of doing this would be to replace Click's event handler with a command with this quite cumbersome syntax:

```
        <Button Content="Test" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.OnClickCommand}"></Button>
```

And then define the command in your MainWindow:

```
    public ICommand OnButtonClick
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                this.Text.Text = "Updated";
            });
        }
    }
```

**3. Define the event handlers in App.xaml.cs and use that to route the event handlers**

I don't recommend this as it get tiresome to keep things synced but it's possible. Create and event handler in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Then use the sender to access the MainWindow instance and call it's method:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Window.GetWindow((DependencyObject)sender);

        mainWindow.DoWork();
    }
```

In my second example Command is defined like the following:

```
    public class Command : ICommand
    {
        public delegate void ICommandOnExecute();
        private ICommandOnExecute _execute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public Command(ICommandOnExecute onExecuteMethod)
        {
            _execute = onExecuteMethod;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks to all answers. i guess i can throw my whole project in the trash and start to learn from the beginning. mvvm, commands etc. :-) weird that i've done courses about WPF and bought books about WPF and there was nothing about mvvm. and no it's absolutely neccesary and you can't do anything without it :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. See [MSDN documentation for Code-Behind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc221357(v=vs.95)):

> The event handlers you write must be instance methods defined by the
>   partial class within the namespace identified by x:Class. **You cannot
>   qualify the name of an event handler to instruct a XAML processor to
>   look for that handler in a different class scope.** You also cannot use
>   a static method as an event handler.

In WPF you can use a [behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726531(v=expression.40)) instead.

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
<Button Content="btnWithBehavior">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:HandleButtonClick/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>

public class HandleButtonClick : Behavior<Button>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Click += AssociatedObject_Click; ;
    }
    private void AssociatedObject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Move your MainWindow.Button_Click here;
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.Click -= AssociatedObject_Click;
    }
}
```