# Bind static method from another class as handler for WPF control event

Tags: wpf

I have a window, say `MainWindow` with some NumericUpDowns. I have another window `MyCalculatorWindow` like this:

```
public class MyCalculatorWindow : Window {

    public static void LongUpDown_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
         // Show calculator and set numeric value when OK button is pressed.
    }

    // The rest of the MyCalculator functionality...
}
```

Is there a way to bind that static method to the `TouchUp` event handler property of `LongUpDown`s in xaml (ideally to all of them at once)? Something like this:

```
<xctk:LongUpDown TouchUp="{Binding Something??? MyCalculator.LongUpDown_TouchUp}" />
```

Comment: You can't bind a method. An event handler in the code behind of MainWindow may simply call the static method, although this is terrible design. Better call an instance method (non-static) on the appropriate MyCalculatorWindow instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click-Event from MainWindow.xaml.cs in App.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685633/click-event-from-mainwindow-xaml-cs-in-app-xaml)

Comment: @Clemens would you post a draft of this approach as an answer? I previously had `MyCalculatorWindow` as singleton returned from `static MyCalculatorWindow.GetCalculator()` and used `Window.Resources > ObjectDataProvider` to get the instance. Is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to bind that static method to the `TouchUp` event handler property of LongUpDowns in xaml (ideally to all of them at once)? Something like this:

No, there isn't. The XAML compiler can only find event handlers in the same class as the element itself.

You could define a `TouchUp` event handler in the code-behind file for the view where the `<xctk:LongUpDown />` element is and call the static method from there. It's a one-liner:

```
private void Window65_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e) => MyCalculatorWindow.LongUpDown_TouchUp(sender, e);
```